# Rule dependency graph in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Let's say I want to make a rule dependency graph for a Prolog program, in Prolog. For instance, the following program

```
foo(X) :- bar(X, 0).
bar(A, B) :- quux(A), coox(B).
baz.
```

would result in the following being true (by using `assert`):

```
depends(foo, [bar]).
depends(bar, [quux, coox]).
depends(baz, []).
```

Or something like the above that I could easily use to make a graph. The approach I've been thinking about is reading the lines of input file as strings and performing some simple search-and-replace on them, but that looks like an ugly, un-Prologlike hack. Any other options that make use of Prolog's metalogical capabilities?

Comment: Since Prolog allows predicate name overloading based on the number of arguments, you'd better use `Name/NArgs` terms instead of simple names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to read the file in as (unstructured) *string*: A Prolog source file is a sequence of valid Prolog *terms*, you can read the clauses with (for example) read/1 and reason about them just as you would about any other terms. (:-)/2 is already a predefined operator, and you can then easily inspect the clauses with Prolog's built-in metapredicates (arg/3, functor/3, =../2 etc.). This automatically takes care of source-level comments etc. just as you would expect.

Comment: Syntactical follow-up question: how do I make a rule that will accept input as depends(foo :- bar, baz, X, Y)? The way I have it right now, I have to wrap the "foo :- bar, baz" part in parens.

Comment: Yes you of course have to write it as depends((foo :- bar,baz), X, Y), otherwise (i.e., in depends(foo :- bar, baz, X, Y) ), the atom "baz" is the second argument of depends/4 instead of part of its first argument. However, if you read clauses from a file this issue does not arise: consider ?- read(Clause). If you enter "foo :- bar, baz." (without quotes), Clause is automatically unified to the term (foo:-bar,baz), and you can continue with ?- ..., clause_dependencies(Clause, Ds), assertz(clause_depends_on(Clause, Ds)). assuming you have defined clause_dependencies/2 as desired.